# Can a WebExtension override server IP addresses?

Tags: dns, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible for a WebExtension to override the IP address of a server, or to modify/intercept DNS requests or override the DNS cache? I'm trying to code a WebExtension that provides browsers with the same functionality as [cURL's `--resolve`](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2018/04/05/curl-another-host/).

Specifically, to:

- connect to a different IP than the one published in DNS
- add entries for particular non-existent domains that the user wishes to resolve *as if* they existed (e.g. patching in access to [an OpenNIC site](https://wiki.opennic.org/opennic/dot/null) via a WebExtension could be more robust and far less disruptive to the broader system/network than playing whack-a-mole with volunteer-run DNS servers that never stay online for more than a few years)
- "resolve" particular entries while the relevant DNS server is offline
- cache or pin DNS entries in a software-defined way in preparation for a known upcoming DNS poisoning attack

In short: to simulate the effect of a `hosts` file, but without administrative privileges / messing with the rest of the system.

Comment: I will accept a conversion of this answer to Chrome iff it is not possible in Firefox _and_ it is possible in Chrome.

Comment: I believe your question to be offtopic here as not related to programming. There is however another option far simpler of all the above: just configure Firefox to use a specific DOH endpoint and control that nameserver where you can completely define how names will be resolved. This remains completely contained inside the browser.

Comment: No, extensions can't do that.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like [WebExtensions _can_ conditionally force requests through a proxy of their choice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy/onRequest), and, as of FF57 (rel. Nov. 2017), [it's become possible for WebExtension-induced proxying to handle DNS requests as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46107763/1874170). So, while it would require _some_ "buddy-script" software to open up a TCP port to run a DNS-mangling proxy server, this could run trivially on the PC or even a VPS, without admin rights or system configuration changes.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The question is specifically about the capabilities/limitations of an API in a somewhat popular software development platform. If that's not a programming question, I'd be very curious to see what is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but (for now) **not trivially**.

WebExtensions cannot rewrite these responses directly, but they *can* use the [`browser.proxy.onRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy/onRequest) API with [`ProxyInfo.proxyDNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/proxy/ProxyInfo#:%7E:text=proxyDNS) to redirect DNS requests for affected domains through a SOCKS4 or SOCKS5 proxy which mangles the responses.

You will, however, need a [Native Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) component (or a VPS, etc.) to actually run this proxy -- at least until Firefox [adds support for WebExtension-run sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67522655/1874170) (or provides a built-in non-socket-based proxying API).